# Using sum aggregate function on varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which retrieves the difference between two DateTime columns (TimeOut and TimeIn) along with a item name(ItemName):

```
 SELECT ItemName,CONVERT(nvarchar,(TimeOut- TimeIn), 108) AS TimeTaken FROM TimeTable
```

This gives me all the values like how I want but I want to group it by ItemName so that I get the sum of common item's time taken.

I tried doing this, but it didn't work well. Any suggestion will be helpful, thanks!

```
SELECT ItemName,sum(CONVERT(nvarchar,(TimeOut- TimeIn), 108)) AS TimeTaken FROM TimeTable group by ItemName
```

I cannot sum varchar, but what do I do?

I want something like:

```
    Pen       08:00
    Pencil    13:00
    Marker    53:00
```

Instead of:

```
    Pen       04:00
    Pencil    05:00
    Pen       04:00
    Marker    13:00
    Marker    40:00
    Pencil    08:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `DATEDIFF` function

```
SELECT ItemName,sum( DATEDIFF(SECOND, TimeOut, TimeIn)) AS TimeTaken FROM TimeTable group by ItemName
```